# What is an observable random variable?

Tags: statistics

On Wikipedia, a statistic is defined to be an observable random variable ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic ). However, neither of the terms statistic and observable is formally defined in the article. So what exactly is a statistic?

Comment: What is wrong with *a function of a sample where the function itself is independent of the sample's distribution; that is, the function can be stated before realization of the data. The term statistic is used both for the function and for the value of the function on a given sample*?

Comment: From the information provided in your question, "statistic" *is* formally defined: in terms of "observable". It is just the latter term that is not defined.

Comment: @did: There's nothing wrong with it, but I was looking for a rigorous definition in terms of probability spaces and functions on them.